# How to Remove last Comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code generates a comma separated string to provide a list of ids to the query string of another page, but there is an extra comma at the end of the string. How can I remove or avoid that extra comma?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('td.title_listing :checkbox').change(function() {
            $('#cbSelectAll').attr('checked', false);
        });
    });
    function CotactSelected() {
        var n = $("td.title_listing input:checked");
        alert(n.length);
        var s = "";
        n.each(function() {
            s += $(this).val() + ",";
        });
        window.location = "/D_ContactSeller.aspx?property=" + s;
        alert(s);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `Array.join`

```
var s = "";
n.each(function() {
    s += $(this).val() + ",";
});
```

becomes:

```
var a = [];
n.each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val());
});
var s = a.join(', ');
```

Comment: @Filburt I don't think so its best solution because the processing time will be more in compare to firstone.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal You should provide some test results to proof that.

Comment: @Filburt If it is true, which I havent formally verified myself, whether it *is* the best solution still really depends on what you're doing ... readability and maintainability are often more important than micro-optimization.

Answer (score 27):

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
```

Comment: Simple is the best :-)

Comment: No it is **not** the *best* because it does not validate that the last char in the string actually *is* a `comma`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Slice) method with a negative `endSlice` argument:

```
n = n.slice(0, -1); // last char removed, "abc".slice(0, -1) == "ab"
```

Or you can use the [`$.map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) method to build your comma separated string:

```
var s = n.map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join();

alert(s);
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of removing it, you can simply skip adding it in the first place:

```
var s = '';
n.each(function() {
   s += (s.length > 0 ? ',' : '') + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: @Sanju: What happens when you try to use it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Actually it doesn't worked without any error message.
I have done it by the way i was doing earlier.

Comment: @Sanju: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 5):

**Using `substring`**

```js
var strNumber = "3623,3635,";

document.write(strNumber.substring(0, strNumber.length - 1));
```

**Using `slice`**

```js
document.write("3623,3635,".slice(0, -1));
```

**Using `map`**

```js
var strNumber = "3623,3635,";

var arrData = strNumber.split(',');

document.write($.map(arrData, function(value, i) {
  return value != "" ? value : null;
}).join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Use `Array.join`**

```js
var strNumber = "3623,3635,";
var arrTemp = strNumber.split(',');
var arrData = [];

$.each(arrTemp, function(key, value) {
  //document.writeln(value);
  if (value != "")
    arrData.push(value);
});

document.write(arrData.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using 'normal' javascript:

```
var truncated = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A more primitive way is to change the `each` loop into a `for` loop

```
for(var x = 0; x < n.length; x++ ) {
  if(x < n.length - 1)
    s += $(n[x]).val() + ",";
  else
    s += $(n[x]).val();
}
```

Comment: Why? If you need access to the index of the current item, `.each()` does provide that.

Answer (score 1):

Sam's answer is the best so far, but I think [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) would be a better choice than [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in this case. You're transforming a list of elements into a list of their values, and that's exactly the sort of thing `map` is designed for.

```
var list = $("td.title_listing input:checked")
    .map(function() { return $(this).val(); })
    .get().join(', ');
```

Edit: Whoops, I missed that CMS beat me to the use of `map`, he just hid it under a `slice` suggestion that I skipped over.

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript function :

```
var removeLastChar = function(value, char){
    var lastChar = value.slice(-1);
    if(lastChar == char) {
      value = value.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var nums = '1,2,3,4,5,6,';
var result = removeLastChar(nums, ',');
console.log(result);
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3g3t/)**

Comment: that's not a good code. what if I write a comma in between the values?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below extension method:

```
String.prototype.trimEnd = function (c) {
    c = c ? c : ' ';
    var i = this.length - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 && this.charAt(i) == c; i--);
    return this.substring(0, i + 1);
}
```

So that you can use it like :

```
var str="hello,";
str.trimEnd(',');
```

Output: **hello**.

for more extension methods, check below link:
[Javascript helper methods](http://spshell.blogspot.in/2015/03/jqery-helper-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method:

```
    var str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,';
    strclean = str+'#';
    strclean = $.trim(strclean.replace(/,#/g, ''));
    strclean = $.trim(str.replace(/#/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer

```js
var string = "apple,orange,strawberry";
var totalstringcount = string.split(",").length;
console.log("Before removing comma - "totalstringcount);

var laststring = string.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
var totalstringcount2 = laststring.split(",").length;
console.log("After removing comma - "totalstringcount2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 s = s.TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());
```