# Get Multiple Values with comma separated Using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I am new in PHP and JavaScript. I have a code of Dropdown Checkbox. I want to try get out values of checked options with comma separate like `1,2,3`

My problem is that when i run my code my output have one extra comma at the end like `1,2,3,` and my desired output is `1,2,3`

Here is my code

**HTML Part**

```
<select id="agency" multiple="multiple">
<?php
if (is_array($rating_agencies) && !empty($rating_agencies)) {
    foreach ($rating_agencies as $rating_agencie) {
        echo '<option value="'.$rating_agencie->ID.'"';
        echo '>';
        echo $rating_agencie->name;
        echo '</option>';
    } 
}           
?>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />
```

**Java Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#agency').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#agency option:selected");
            var message = "";
            selected.each(function () {
                message += $(this).val() + ",";
            });
            alert(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In PHP you can use `rtrim()`..

Comment: You can use `$.map()` as `var selected = $("#agency option:selected").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();`

Comment: @FrayneKonok where i use this?

Comment: I would probably check if the message is empty and if it's false i wouldnt provide a comma, otherwise fist appenda comma,t hen the value.

Comment: Looks you need it in javascript `message = message.slice(0, -1);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047491/how-to-remove-last-comma

Comment: slice(0,-1) : to remove last chracter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slice to remove the last comma.

```
$('#btnSelected').click(function () {
    var selected = $("#agency option:selected");
    var message = "";
    selected.each(function () {
        message += $(this).val() + ",";
    });
    message = message.slice(0, -1);
    alert(message);
});
```

This is your question solution, OR you can go with @Rayon.

Answer (score 2):

> Use [**`jQuery.map`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) with [**`Array#join`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

`.get()` will return `basic-array` instead of `array-of-objects`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#agency').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
  $('#btnSelected').click(function() {
    var message = $("#agency option:selected").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(message.join(','));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **slice** function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#agency').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#agency option:selected");
            var message = "";
            selected.each(function () {
                message += $(this).val() + ",";

            });
            message = message.slice(0, -1);
            alert(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the value instead of option:selected, It may work for you

```
var selected = $("#agency").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

use **rtrim** method in **php**

```
// $commaString = "1,2,3,";
  $string = rtrim($commaString,",");
  // output 
  // 1,2,3
```

in **Javascript**

```
var comma_string = "1,2,3,";
string = comma_string.replace(/,+$/,'');
```

You can use in either side as your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$rating_agencies = array_filter($rating_agencies)` before your "if" statement.