# Avoid the additional comma in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.input').each(function() {
            divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            });
            values += this.value + ','
        });
        $("#configsize").text(values);
 }
```

Here is the code in Jquery. I need the data to comma separated. However, the above said function is able to achieve the same. But, is adding an additional comma at the end..

How do I correct this?

Comment: You could try it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047516/2943218

Comment: I am new to Jquery. How do I incorporate the same here. Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the last `,` by doing something like this:

```
var values = [];
$('.input').each(function() {
  values.push(this.value);
});
$("#configsize").text(values.join(', '));
```

For more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047491/how-to-remove-last-comma/2047516#2047516)